# Can someone describe SO(n)/SO(n-1) for me?

Tags: group-theory

I don't have a ton of experience with group theory, but this came up in a topology class and I was just wondering if someone could give me an intuition for this quotient space, and describe what group actions look like - I'm trying to look at this from a group theoretic point of view but then define a quotient map and prove things about that.

Comment: What do you can say about this group action: $SO(n)\times \Bbb{S}^n\mapsto \Bbb{S}^n$ given by $A\cdot x$?

Comment: I mean, describe the isotropy group at the point $(0,0,\ldots,0,1)$.

Comment: Ah I'm sorry I'm not familiar with isotropy groups; could you rephrase your comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group $SO(n+1)$ acts on $S^n$ transitively, so we have a surjection $SO(n+1) \to S^n$ given by $g\to g.x_0$ for some fixed $x_0\in S^n$. For any $p\in S^n$, the preimage $f^{-1}(p)$ is isomorphic to the stabilizer $\{g\in S^n:\, g.x_0 = x_0\} = SO(n)$. (If the latter result isn't clear, assume without loss of generality that $f^{-1}(p)$ or $x_0$ is simply $(1, 0, \dots, 0)$; then the set of matrices in question is $(1)\oplus SO(n)\subset SO(n+1)$.) Putting this all together, we get a homeomorphism $SO(n+1)/SO(n) \to S^n$ defined by $g \to g.x_0$. It's not quite canonical; we need to specify which copy of $SO(n)$ inside $SO(n+1)$ we're killing, at that corresponds to the choice of point $x_0$. Showing that this map is continuous is mostly just a matter of unwinding the definitions; showing that its inverse is continuous is just a matter of noting that the spaces here are compact.

Comment: Ah wow thanks so much. Is there a similar way of looking at the quotient map from SO(n) to the quotient space? Or am I just not seeing it

Comment: The map $SO(n) \to SO(n)/SO(n-1)$? On the level of sets, it's just the quotient map of groups $SO(n) \to SO(n)/SO(n-1)$; the quotient space topology makes that function continuous (by definition). There's really not much going on there; it's just killing the stabilizers of points to make the map $g \to g.x_0$ are homeomorphism rather than just a surjection.